# bind9 zone transfer problem - not authoritive

Tags: debian

I've been beating myself up trying to figure this out.  ns1 seems to work as normal.  ns2 however isn't receiving the zone transfers.  Maybe I just need another eyeball on the issue!

---

ns1 named.conf:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
//include "/etc/bind/named.conf.transfer";
//include "/etc/bind/rndc.key";
include "/etc/bind/tsig.key";

//controls {
//      inet 127.0.0.1 port 953
//              allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
//};
```

ns1 tsig.key  (edited key for security)

```
key "TRANSFER" {
          algorithm hmac-md5;
          secret "/QUbT7wtaTrCQUg4sNC9WA==";
};
server 24.119.63.195 {
        keys {
                TRANSFER;
    };
};
```

ns1 named.conf.options

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        dnssec-validation auto;
        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
        dnssec-enable yes;
};
```

ns1 named.conf.local sample ( all entries follow pattern )

```
zone "woodcreationsok.com" { 
    type master; 
    file "/etc/bind/zones/woodcreationsok.com.zone"; 
    };
```

ns1 sample zone file

```
$ORIGIN woodcreationsok.com
$TTL 86400 
woodcreationsok.com. IN    SOA    ns1.46-10.com.    admin.46-10.com. (
                0000022510  ; Serial
                3H          ; refresh after 3 hours 
                1H          ; retry after 1 hour
                8W          ; expire after 8 weeks
                1D)         ; minimum TTL of 1 day 

    ; Name Server
    IN  NS  ns1.46-10.com.  ; Joplin,MO USA
    IN  NS  ns2.46-10.com.  ; Joplin,MO USA

    ; Mail Exchanger
    IN  MX  50 mail.46-10.com.  ; Joplin,MO USA

    ; Addresses
woodcreationsok.com.        IN A            24.119.63.196
www         IN CNAME        24.119.63.196
```

---

ns2 named.conf

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
include "/etc/bind/tsig.key";
```

ns2 tsig.key (edited key for security)

```
key "TRANSFER" {
          algorithm hmac-md5;
          secret "/QUbT7wtaTrCQUg4sNC9WA==";
};
server 24.119.63.194 {
        keys {
                TRANSFER;
    };
};
```

ns2 named.conf.options

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    dnssec-validation auto;
dnssec-enable yes;
    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

ns2 syslog sample  ( all domains mentioned are domains served by us )

```
Feb 26 10:47:43 ns2 named[12483]: client 24.119.63.194#39371: received notify for zone 'watsonandsonsconstruction.co': TSIG 'transfer': not authoritative
Feb 26 10:47:43 ns2 named[12483]: client 24.119.63.194#39371: received notify for zone 'bigkeiths.com': TSIG 'transfer': not authoritative
Feb 26 10:47:56 ns2 named[12483]: client 66.249.75.235#60473: query (cache) 'www.farmtireservice.com/A/IN' denied
Feb 26 10:48:00 ns2 named[12483]: client 204.194.237.17#57552: query (cache) 'www.bigkeiths.com/AAAA/IN' denied
Feb 26 10:48:00 ns2 named[12483]: client 204.194.237.17#12719: query (cache) 'www.bigkeiths.com/AAAA/IN' denied
```

Any help is much appreciated!  Also, since I'm new to dns admin... are all those *query (cache) domain.tld denied* a computer in internet land asking for the domain to be resolved?

Comment: Have you considered using Power DNS as a superslave? It has the advantage of not requiring it to be configured with the zone, like @mgorven states. You just make it a superslave, and it will transfer.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably forgotten to configure ns2 with the appropriate secondary zone. You should have the following somewhere in the configuration (probably `named.conf.local`):

```
zone "woodcreationsok.com" {
    type slave;
    file "woodcreationsok.com";
    masters { 24.119.63.194; }; // primary nameserver IP
}
```